# How to use AddAzureAppConfiguration overloaded method with action parameter

Tags: c#, azure

```cs
public static IConfigurationBuilder AddConfigurationManagement(
    this IConfigurationBuilder builder,
    Uri connectionUri,
    string tenantId,
    string trimPrefix = null,
    string refreshKey = null,
    string configurationLabel = null,
    int cacheExpirationInSeconds = DefaultCacheExpirationInSeconds)
{
    builder = builder ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
    connectionUri = connectionUri ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionUri));
    tenantId = tenantId ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tenantId));

//problem here
    builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options => ConnectTest(options));
//this can work
    builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration1(options => ConnectTest(options));

    return builder;
}

public static IConfigurationBuilder AddAzureAppConfiguration1(this IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, Action<AzureAppConfigurationOptions> action)
{
    if (action != null)
    {
        AzureAppConfigurationOptions options = new AzureAppConfigurationOptions();
        action(options);
    }

    return configurationBuilder;
}

private static AzureAppConfigurationOptions ConnectTest(AzureAppConfigurationOptions options)
{
    return options;
}

//this is the meta function
public static IConfigurationBuilder AddAzureAppConfiguration(this IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, Action<AzureAppConfigurationOptions> action, bool optional = false);

//this is local connectFunction
private static AzureAppConfigurationOptions Connect(
    AzureAppConfigurationOptions options,
    Uri connectionUri,
    string tenantId,
    string trimPrefix,
    string refreshKey,
    string configurationLabel,
    int featureManagementCacheExpirationInSeconds)
{
    DefaultAzureCredentialOptions defaultAzureCredentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
    {
        SharedTokenCacheTenantId = tenantId,
    };
    options.Connect(connectionUri, new DefaultAzureCredential(defaultAzureCredentialOptions));
    AzureAppConfigurationOptionsBuilder(options, trimPrefix, refreshKey, configurationLabel, featureManagementCacheExpirationInSeconds);
    return options;
}
```

Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration 5.0.0

builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options => ConnectTest(options));
builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration1(options => ConnectTest(options));

when use AddAzureAppConfiguration the method ConnectTest doesn't be called
But it works when I use AddAzureAppConfiguration1 written by my own
What's going on?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. As stated above, please provide enough information. For help, please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `Connect` method on the `options` object:

```
builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
        options.Connect("<your-connection-string>")
```

The parameters you're passing into the `Connect` method are not available on the [`Connect()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.azureappconfiguration.azureappconfigurationoptions.connect?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-extensions-configuration-azureappconfiguration-azureappconfigurationoptions-connect(system-string)) on the `AzureAppConfigurationOptions` class and it seems you're calling your own local `Connect` method.

If this is intentional, please provide the code if the `Connect()` method so we can see if there's any issues there.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I simplified the code and posted the connect method, options =>
         options.Connect("<your-connection-string>" This step is placed in the connect method, but the problem is that the connect method cannot be entered at runtime, If use AddAzureAppConfiguration1 instead, it will be fine